# Changing from getActiveCell(); to getting a range instead

Tags: google-apps-script

This may be fairly simple for you guys.

How to replace getActiveCell() for something I dont need to be online for the script to run, so I can set it up based on a time-trigger?

Check the code block below.

```
function MoveRows() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Requests";
  var sheetNameToMoveTo = "Approved";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = range.getRow();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch &&
    sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue() == "Y" &&
    sheet.getRange(row, 12).getValue() == "Approved") {
{

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 
sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
    }}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to redefine your task. What's the purpose of the active cell. How is it picked by the human? Apply that selection logic to your program.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code a bit I'm guessing this maybe close to what your looking for.

```
function MoveRows() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Requests";
  var sheetNameToMoveTo = "Approved";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Requests')
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values=range.getValues();
  var row = range.getRow();
  if (values[0][7] == "Y" && values[0][11] == "Approved") {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    range.moveTo(targetRange);//you could also just do targetSheet.appendRow(values[0]); Your call
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```